# Convert .val() to float to return numbers from select options as float?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Why does `.val()` return numbers as text instead of float, using apostrophes inside the array?

```
<select id = "multiselect" multiple = "multiple"> 
  <option value="1" class="selected">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2" class="selected">Text 2</option>
  <option value="3">Text 3</option>
  <option value="4" class="selected">Text 4</option>
</select>

var selectedvalues = $('#multiselect').val();

console.log(selectedvalues); // returns ['1','2','4'] instead of [1,2,4]
```

**Can I simply convert the array to float/numbers?**

or is there another simple way to extract all values of selected options and put inside an array?

I tried parseFloat but it doesn't seem to work with array as it only returns 1.

Comment: thanks, ok so I will need to use JS to extract all values into an array, thanks

Comment: Why? Because an attribute is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `parseFloat()` on each array element.

```
var selectedValues = $('#multiselect').val().map(parseFloat);
```

Comment: wow that was quick thanks and exactly what I was asking for, love the short code with JQuery and didn't want a longer JS version to extract all values into an array, cheers.

Comment: JS is really not that much more code. Actually less since there is not a huge JS library involved. `const selectedValues = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#multiselect option:checked')).map(elem => +elem.value);`

Comment: @epascarello Except you misspelled `:selected`.

Comment: Selector works for both in chrome. :)

Comment: @epascarello Oops, that's standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked `:selected` is the jQuery extension.